# Aggragation function in pandas with missing data

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a data frame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = ['2010-01-01', '2010-01-02','2010-01-01','2010-01-01', '2010-01-01','2010-01-01',
        '2010-01-02', '2010-01-02','2010-01-02','2010-01-03', '2010-01-04','2010-01-04', 
        '2010-01-04', '2010-01-01','2010-01-05','2010-01-05', '2010-01-05','2010-01-01']
amounts = [14, 22, 10, 65, 23, 43, 12, 49, 10, 10, 20, 12, 12, 108, 61, 98, 17, 43 ]
types = ['Type1', 'Type1', 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type1', 'Type3',
        'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type2', 'Type3',
        'Type2', 'Type1', 'Type3', 'Type2', 'Type1', 'Type3']
my_data = {'Date': dates, 'Amount': amounts, 'Type': types}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=my_data)
```

And I want to plot graphs (3  plots 1 for each unique Type) for mean Amount per each day for each Type. But after aggregating I do not have zeros in those days where there were no Amount so there are 5  dates but because of dataset in some Types there are no data of each Type so graphs can not be plotted. Is there a way to solve it? Thanks a lot!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dates_unique = df["Date"].unique()
types_unique = df["Type"].unique()

for Type in types_unique:
    values = df.loc[df['Type'] == Type].groupby(df.Date).Amount.mean()
    plt.plot_date(dates_unique, values, label=Type)
```

Comment: `sns.lineplot(data=df, hue='Type', x='Date',y='Amount')`?

Comment: Not exactly. I need to calculate first mean of each Type per each day and then plot it. But thanks for the hint anyway!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what `sns.lineplot` does.

Comment: Another way is pivot_table: `df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Type', values='Amount').plot()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `0` (not `NaN`) to replace missing data, you should specify it explicitly.  Further, I would recommend to resample to the frequency at which you intend to plot your data, so that dates that are missing entirely are not "glossed over" but do appear with 0 count).

So, for example:

Alternative 1:

```py
z = df.groupby([
    pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D'), 'Type',
])['Amount'].mean().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Alternative 2:

```py
z = df.pivot_table(
    index='Date', columns='Type', values='Amount',
    fill_value=0).resample('D').sum()
```

In either case, `z` is now:

```
Type            Type1  Type2  Type3
Date                               
2010-01-01  38.750000     65     43
2010-01-02  14.666667     49      0
2010-01-03   0.000000     10      0
2010-01-04   0.000000     16     12
2010-01-05  17.000000     98     61
```

and you can readily plot it:

```py
z.plot(style='-o')
```

[image]